# Value of input text REACT

Tags: reactjs, button, event-handling

how can I set the value of my input box when the button is clicked. When i Clicked the button it will generate a string and put it inside the this.state.classCode.

What's my error? thanks in advance

```
this.handleGetCode =  this.handleGetCode.bind(this);

handleGetCode(event){
        const cryptoRandomString = require('crypto-random-string');

        let random = cryptoRandomString({length: 4});
        let randomUp = random.toUpperCase();
        let classcodes = this.state.classCode;
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: classcodes});
    }

<div className="col-md-12 m-b-15">
     <label className="control-label">Class Code<span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
     <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Class Code" name="classCode" value={this.state.classCode} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
     <button onClick={this.handleGetCode}>Get Code</button>
</div>
```

Comment: may be directly set this.setState({classCode: classcodes}) inside handleGetCode instead of [event.target.name]?

Comment: have you implemented handleChange()?

Comment: try this. but it's not button Click `onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      classcodes: event.target.value
    })
  }`

Comment: update the code and show the state as well please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your statemnet **When i Clicked the button it will generate a string and put it inside the this.state.classCode** , you are not using the newly generated string anywhere. And also, assuming that you already have a onChange handler in place, you could modify handleGetCode() like this

```
handleGetCode(event){
        const cryptoRandomString = require('crypto-random-string');
        let random = cryptoRandomString({length: 4});
        let randomUp = random.toUpperCase();
        this.setState({classCode: randomUp});
}
```